# USB headset causes bizarre system behavior

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a Sennheiser headset that causes bizarre system behavior when it is plugged in, including:

- **Graphical corruption**: all of the system text, such as the toolbar clock, shifts to a very different font, and the screen occasionally flashes black. Menus appear in windows where they should be hidden (such as the terminal). I suspect the system is failing to read config files somehere.
- **Programs fail to start or start slowly**: on startup, many of my toolbar widgets (network status, load monitor) do not load, but as soon as I unplug the headset they pop into place. If I try to start Chrome from the taskbar, nothing happens for a good minute or two.
- **File corruption**: when Chrome finally does start, it reports that my profile on disk is corrupt. I'm guessing whatever is locking disk access also leads to the graphical corruption above.

As soon as I unplug the headset, the system mostly returns to normal.

I see none of this behavior on Windows, the headset works fine there, and Sennheiser claims it's 100% compatible with Windows/Mac/Linux. I've tried multiple computers running different versions of Ubuntu, and multiple USB cables, all with the same behavior, so it's clearly an incompatibility between the headset and Ubuntu.

Looking at the logs, I do see some strange USB errors when the headset is plugged in, but I don't know how to interpret them: http://pastebin.com/yGyGcHMP

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or at least narrow down the root cuase?

Here are some workarounds I've tried:

- **Disabling headset using modprobe and xorg**: Blacklisting snd_usb_audio via modprobe solves the problem, but it also disables my webcam mic, so it's not really an option... I need *some* sort of microphone available. The headset also provides an HID, and that module obviously can't be disabled, so I also have to add this to xorg.conf:

  ```
  Section "InputClass"
      Identifier  "Sennheiser Communications"
      MatchVendor "Sennheiser Communications"
      Option      "Ignore" "true"
  EndSection
  ```
- **Disabling headset by deauthorizing USB device**: This is the workaround I am currently using. Obviously it doesn't allow me to use the headset on Ubuntu, but it at least avoids the even jankier workaround of unplugging the headset every time I boot into Ubuntu. I added the following udev rule:

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1395", ATTR{idProduct}=="740a", ATTR{authorized}="0"
  ```

Comment: Does Windows run on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, on one of the computers Windows runs dual-boot with Ubuntu. The other computer runs only Ubuntu.